# Past Tweets counts of user for last month?

Tags: android, twitter

I want to find twitter user's past month tweet's total count, Is there any `API` which give me this..?

Please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using api,

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=username8&count=200&page=1

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=username8&count=200&page=2

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=username&count=200&page=3

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=username&count=200&page=4
.
.
.
.
etc.......Until you get the exact date of 1 month ago from "created_at" tag,you will get the count of tweet from that...:)

Answer (score 0):

[GET account/totals](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/totals):

```
Returns the current count of friends, followers, updates (statuses) and favorites of the authenticating user
```